# BigQuery - Shuffle By error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of about 5M rows.  Note this is just a poc.   Ultimately we will need to be in the TB range.  I am doing a self join to find permutations of products for a market basket analysis.

I need to find the number of times the combination occurs in a basket, the ratio of occurrences to total baskets, and the number of times the item occurs in all baskets.  This is pretty standard.   BigQuery does not support selects in the predicate of another select so I needed to create another join I suppose.  Here's what I came up with -

```
select twoItem.upc1,twoItem.upc2,twoItem.twoItemOccurrences, totalUpc.totalUpcCount
from
(
    select purchase1.upc as upc1,purchase2.upc as upc2,count(upc1) as twoItemOccurrences
    from
    conagra.purchase as purchase1
    join each conagra.purchase as purchase2
    on purchase1.upc = purchase2.upc
    group by upc1,upc2
) as twoItem
JOIN EACH 
(
    select purchase3.upc as upc3, count(*) as totalUpcCount
    from conagra.purchase as purchase3
    group by upc3
) as totalUpc
on totalUpc.upc3 = twoItem.upc1
LIMIT 50;
```

I get the following error:

> `SHUFFLE BY` may only be applied to parallelizable queries, but query is not parallelizable: `(SELECT * FROM (SELECT [purchase3.upc] AS [upc3], COUNT(*) AS [totalUpcCount]...`

Maybe an unpublished limitation?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try running these with `GROUP EACH BY` on your inner queries. We'll improve the response message for queries like this.

Comment: I have a similar query that reports the same error. Turning all my `GROUP BY` to `GROUP EACH BY` didn't help. @michael-manoochehri Can you share what might have caused this?

Comment: My query is pretty long. See if this can help you locate the query:

datasetId: "_b4baa84cc768743eba28472b9c2ad40ecf37c576"
projectId: "876515819216"
tableId: "anonfaff8cc9_a5fc_4421_8da0_02289266765b". If not I can email the exact query to you.